# How to extract values from a column into the dataframe by matching two other columns in R

Tags: r

I have a question like this:
There are two dataframe with different rows. I want to extract values from "bb" in dfb in to "bb" in dfa by matching "aa" field in the two dataframe.

```
dfa <- data.frame(cbind(c(1,2,3,4,5), c(0,0,0,0,0)))
colnames(dfa) <- c("aa", "bb")
dfb <- data.frame(cbind(c(3,5,1), c(8,6,10)))
colnames(dfb) <- c("aa", "bb")
```

The result of dfa should be like this:

```
aa  bb
1   10
2   0
3   8
4   0
5   6
```

Currently I use a loop to solve it like this:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(dfa)) {
    for (j in 1:nrow(dfb)) {
      if(dfa$aa[i] == dfb$aa[j] ) {
        dfa$bb[i] <- dfb$bb[j] }
    }
  }
```

But I have a big data, so it is relatedly slow. 
Are there any functions or direct ways to solve this?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use dplyr, this is pretty straightforward (first join the 2 dataframes, then select the right values from column bb.x and bb.y based on NA values in the bb.x. Finally keep only the required columns.

```
dfa %>% 
  dplyr::left_join(dfb, by = "aa") %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(bb = ifelse(is.na(bb.y), bb.x, bb.y)) %>% 
  dplyr::select(aa, bb)
```

Result

```
  aa bb
1  1 10
2  2  0
3  3  8
4  4  0
5  5  6
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `match` :

```
dfa$bb[match(dfb$aa, dfa$aa)] <- dfb$bb
#In this case this will also work
#dfa$bb[dfb$aa] <- dfb$bb

dfa
#  aa bb
#1  1 10
#2  2  0
#3  3  8
#4  4  0
#5  5  6
```

---

If there are values in `dfb` which are not there in `dfa` we can do the same thing other way around

```
dfa$bb <- dfb$bb[match(dfa$aa, dfb$aa)]
```

If we need to replace `NA` with 0, we can do :

```
dfa$bb[is.na(dfa$bb)] <- 0
```

---

This is similar to using `merge`

```
merge(dfa, dfb, all.x = TRUE, by = 'aa')[-2]
```

Comment: When I used "dfa$bb[match(dfb$aa, dfa$aa)] <- dfb$bb", there was error: "NAs are not allowed in subscripted assignments"